# Applescript moving finder window or screen back to first screen

Tags: applescript

I am writing a script and want to hem in the user(s) in the future from errors. The big one I'm working on right now is that the Choose File command box for Finder or AppleScript (doesn't matter) do not contain the "giving up after" option. So while I can set the timeout to a very large number of seconds (5000 for example), I can't get the box to close and reopen without the Apple Events timing out.

So here is one option I've tried. but the problem I have is that if I swipe to another screen, even if I Activate the finder, it will say that it can't find the window "Choose a File"

Is there a way to get the window to follow the swipe or a command with activate that will bring the finder window to the current screen, even if I'm working in say Safari?

The error occurs when I swipe to another screen; see the error below:

error "System Events got an error: Can’t get window \"Choose a File\" of process \"Finder\"." number -1728 from window "Choose a File" of process "Finder"

Script:

try
    with timeout of 5 seconds
        tell application "Finder"
            set theFilestoChoose to every item of (choose file with prompt "Please select the file(s) you would like to move and rename:" with multiple selections allowed) as list
        end tell
    end timeout
on error errStr number errorNumber
    if errorNumber is -1712 then --timeout error
        my closeWindow() --call handler to close window
    end if
end try

on closeWindow()
    tell application "System Events"
        delay 2 -- for observation testing purposes
        set frontmost of process "Finder" to true
        delay 2 -- for observation testing purposes
        click button "Cancel" of window "Choose a File" of process "Finder"
    end tell
end closeWindow

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to look into the defaults setting AutoSwoosh = true; `defaults write com.apple.Dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -bool YES ; KillAll Dock` which makes you go to the active app, if it isn't in the current space, the app itself, (Finder in this case?), shouldn't be assigned to a space.

If that is your basic configuration, then a simple `activate` before it, should bring you directly to your choose file dialog, if it is in another space.

Here is a fleshed out example of embedding the choose file with tell application (path to frontmost application as text):

```
  tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
      set theF to (choose file)
  end tell
```

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly! On first glance, that looks great. I think for you to know if this will work for me, i need to give you a few more details. For right now, Finder, as well as all my other windows are not assigned to any space (they are all unassigned; "None" OSX 10.9.5). So I looked up AutoSwoosh and this article popped up. I'm having a hard time interpreting the guy at the bottom though. http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=23453

Comment: Well, I wrote at the bottom, thing is, I have autoswoosh enabled, and that leads to me being brought into the right space at times. This can be annoying, another approach is to embed __choose file__ with `tell application (path to frontmost application as text)`, this will put the choose file dialog in front of the user where he is at the moment.

Comment: I don't mind being annoying to the user :) (my wife or I) I just want to make sure the process doesn't get error-ed out or timed out. So I apologize if I'm dense, but can you flesh out the "embed choose file with tell application (path to frontmost application as text)"  part for me... with a little explanation of where you'd put it. It sounds like it might work

Comment: I added an example at the end of my answer above. Please check it off as answered, if it works for you.. :)

Comment: I have autoswoosh enabled, I believe. I ran the terminal command, killed the dock and it still wouldn't work. I modified one thing on a whim and it seemed to fix the original script allowing it to work (for a reason I understand), but now I've got another situation to work around. The thing I tweaked was that I assigned finder to all desktops. So that when i start the dialog with choose file in desktop 1 and then swipe to safari in desktop 2, it follows (tho in the background), so that when the on closeWindow() runs, it can still find the finder window opened above. How does frontmost help?

Comment: The frontmost app, helps, in that a dialog, should then, in most cases be displayed right in front of your face, over everything else, forcing you to close or deal with the dialog, before you continue.